# What should I do when it rains blood?

Tags: path-of-exile

At the end of Act 3 of Path of Exile, there is a boss that causes the sky to rain blood (or something that looks much like blood -- perhaps strawberry jam?) This dealt considerable damage over time to my Duelist despite quenching my thirst with a flask of healing.  This killed him.  Luckily he was not a hardcore character and I was able to respawn after the rain stopped.

However, I'm now playing a hardcore character. I would really like to know how to deal with that blood rain attack by the Act 3 finale boss.  Is that attack avoidable in some fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Answer is tricky but simple. When it rains blood, there is a shield that forms around the boss(Dominus). If you are outside of this circle you will receive increasing stacks of the corrupting blood debuff, which causes damage over time. Just enter this area and you will be protected from getting any more stacks of corrupting blood.

To remove any stacks of corrupting blood from before you got inside the circle use a flask with the "of Staunching" suffix, or just wait for them to dissipate on their own.

You will be in range for his close range melee attack so be careful and kite him in that small area if possible or just heal up.

Here are 2 guides by ZiggyD that explain the Dominus fight mechanics in detail

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but i just came across this boss and had the same question (hence why im here).

I actually beat him in hardcore just now using a different method.

I would create a  town portal. Once it starts raining jump in the portal and wait for 20-seconds then go back in, create another portal (in-case it rains again).
Rinse n repeat

Obvious down side is you are using town portals and it feels a lil like cheating.
Up side is u dont have to toe 2 toe this beast.